# Convergence of the iterative method $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha r_k+\beta(x_k-x_{k-1})$ for solving a symmetric and positive definite linear system

Tags: numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra

In a homework problem **(so a hint is sufficient)**, I am asked to determine the convergence of the iterative method $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha r_k+\beta(x_k-x_{k-1})$ for solving a symmetric and positive definite linear system $Ax=b$. here, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are constants that do not depend on $k$, and $r_k=b-Ax_k$ is the $k$th-step residual. These questions are asked:

- In what range of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ does this algorithm converge?
- What are the optimal values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

Let $x^*$ be the solution to $Ax=b$. My attempt is to imitate the proof of the convergence of the steepest descent method $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha r_k$, trying to find an inequality like this: $\|x_{k+1}-x^*\|_A\leq C\|x_k-x^*\|_A$, where $\|v\|_A:=\sqrt{v^TAv}$ is the $A$-norm and $C$ should be some constant possibly related to the eigenvalues of $A$.

If the updating formula does not contain the $\beta(x_k-x_{k-1})$ I can obtain the following ($\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues of $A$):
$$
\|x_{k+1}-x^*\|_A=\|x_k+\alpha(Ax^*-Ax_k)-x^*\|_A=\|(I-\alpha A)(x_k-x^*)\|_A\\
\implies \|x_{k+1}-x^*\|_A\leq\max_i|1-\alpha\lambda_i|\|x_k-x^*\|_A.
$$
However, for $x_{k+1}=x_k+\alpha r_k+\beta(x_k-x_{k-1})$ the above is impossible, since there is an extra $x_{k-1}$ in play. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Apply the eigen-decomposition of $A$ and reduce the problem to the scalar case.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want only a hint, try to define the vector $y_k$ as
$$
y_k = \left[\begin{array}c x_{k+1}\\x_k\end{array}
\right]
$$
and write the same recurrence. Keep also in mind that $A$ is positive definite.